# How to transform database records into XML in C#

Tags: xml

Currently I have a database with different tables.  I would like to map each record for each table to a corresponding predefined XML template to form a XML documents.
For example
One of the tables is person. It has fields like name, age, address.  And its corresponding template is like

```
<person name="" age="">
     <Address> </Address>
 </person>
```

Is there a C# library that will do such a transformation without using the XMLWriter directly?
Thanks

Comment: if you are using SQL server try this - `SELECT * FROM person FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('persons')`

Comment: What is "predefined template"? Is it just a heuristic or are these existing templates? Do the afore-mentioned "templates" align *perfectly* with the database model? Is the goal that one-database-table-XML-document or does the end-result involve an XML hierarchy? If the latter, how is a cyclic or converging relationship graph handled? (These "little details" should be worked out in great detail *first*.)

Comment: Yes. the template will be aligned perfectly with the database model. That is one template per model.  I will first define a template for each table within the database.  Then I will like to read in the template, set the columnmapping and hide any column within the dataset. Then I will call datasetobject.WriteXML().

Comment: My utlimate goal is to transform existing graphics file into WPF based file.  The graphics files is in a proprietary format, but it do have elements similar to WPF.  I am trying to extract the data from the graphics file and put it into a database for further manipulation so as to create neccessary data that can easiy map to WPF format file. I wonder if this has been done in the past so no need to duplicate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be loading them to a DataSet (or DataTable) and serializing the dataset using .NET's [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or using the built-in `WriteXML()` method ([DataSet's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) / [DataTable's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx)).

Another easy option is a simple database query (that applies to SQL 2005 and up):

```
SELECT * FROM People FOR XML AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of is to fill your tables's data into dataset and then use `datasetobject.WriteXml();` for writing data to XML